# No puedo acceder a un servidor de sockets desde una computadora externa cuando lo ejecuto dentro de Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servidor

Estoy desarrollando un servidor en JAVA. Si genero un JAR cualquier aplicacion cliente interna o externa a la computadora puede acceder al servidor. Si lo ejecuto desde Eclipse para poder depurarla las computadoras externas no conectan. Agradeceré cualquier sugerencia. Gracias

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta no es muy clara, echa un vistazo a [ask] y [tour].

Comment: @Francisco podrias aclarar esto para poder depurarla las computadoras externas no te entiendo mucho

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que tengas

Comment: Por ejemplo, si ejecuto un echo server dentro de Eclipse para depurarlo los clientes externos al ordenador donde corre Eclipse no conectan, pero los que corren en el mismo ordenador si lo hacen. Si genero un JAR y ejecuto el echo server fuera de Eclipse cualquier aplicación cliente que corra en el mismo ordenador o en otro ordenador puede conectarse. Podría ser que tenga que habrir algún puerto en el firewal relacionado con Eclipse??? Gracias y Saludos